# Import Figma UI Package to Android

Tags: android-studio, figma

I have crafted a component within Figma, comprising 5 frames, each housing a mask with a nested union. Using Relay, I've assembled the UI package, copied the link, and endeavored to import it into Android Studio.

The import doesn't fail when I press the "Create" button, but the package it's not imported.
I got a warning message before the import:

```
Could not convert node Union: unrecognized type NodeType BooleanOperation
```

I guess the union inside the frames are not allowed (?).

How can I solve it?